# How to fix 405 error code from displaying before auth comes back from supabase

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

I am using Supabase to handle auth in my Sveltekit app. When user logs in with proper credentials after they have signed up, I am getting a quick flash onscreen that says `405 POST method not allowed. No actions exist for this page`. That appears until the session is returned to me from Supabase, and then app redirects as it should properly. Why is this error message flashing and what can I do to prevent this? Do I need to set a boolean `isLoading` and display something over it while networking is happening? Here is my code in `+page.svelte`, thanks a lot!

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { enhance } from '$app/forms'

    // var to track if user is signing in or needs to create new user
    let isSignIn = true
    let email = ''
    let password = ''
    let errorMessage = ''

    // getting our supabase instance to use
    export let data
    let { supabase } = data
    $: ({ supabase } = data)

    // toggles the state
    const setIsSignIn = () => (isSignIn = !isSignIn)

    $: titleText = isSignIn ? 'Sign in' : 'Create new account'
    $: buttonText = isSignIn ? 'Need an account?' : 'Sign in'

    async function handleAuth(event: Event) {
        event.preventDefault() // Prevent the default form submission behavior
        if (isSignIn) {
            let { error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({ email, password })
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
                errorMessage = error.message
            }
        } else {
            let { error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({ email, password })
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
                errorMessage = error.message
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="content">
    <h3>{titleText}</h3>
    <form method="POST" use:enhance on:submit={handleAuth}>
        <input type="email" placeholder="email address" bind:value={email} />
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" bind:value={password} />
        <button class="btn variant-filled" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    {#if errorMessage}
        <div class="error-message">
            <p>{errorMessage}</p>
        </div>
    {/if}

    <button on:click={setIsSignIn}>{buttonText}</button>
</div>
```

I tried to run this code and it does work, however the 405 error is showing up when I don't want that. How can I prevent this bad UI from showing up?